# WP7 Silverlight + XNA: application bar on -> no longer fullscreen xna rendering?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna, fullscreen

I'm working on a hybrid silverlight/XNA app for WP7. I want the XNA part to render the full screen, exept for an application bar, which is silverlight. Without the application bar on, XNA renders fullscreen. As soon as i turn on the application bar, XNA leaves black bands on the top and bottom of the screen (i'm working in landscape mode). The application bar does use the full screen height.

The XAML contains the following lines:

mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="480" d:DesignWidth="728"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="False">

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

I think it's the same problem as this article in French. (because ApplicationBar and SystrayBar are two elements of the shell)

http://blog.naviso.fr/wordpress/?p=1304

Comment: Exactly this. Setting the opacity of the application bar to 0.99 gets rid of the black bands.